Is it safe to assume that if a device is designed to charge via 30 W it can also output 30 W from the very same USB C port?
I would like to connect a 2 0W (could go down to 10 if needed, but not preferred) to a DJI Mini 2 drone USB Type C port.
The device is capable to output 5 V by producer’s sped, but no wattage is declared.
DJI specs expressively say that is supports up to 29 W charge.
Is it safe to assume that it can also output such power, assuming that it is predisposed to outputting power?
EDIT: Despite it being a fairly cheap device, is there any way I can test this without burning the core board?

never assume anything

I recommend procuring a USB-C power meter and messing about.  Most USB ports are protected from overload and the best way to find out the maximum ratings if to see how the output is implemented.  There is probably a tear-down somewhere with IC numbers you can look up to determine absolute maximum ratings.

No, you cannot assume that the drone, as a charging host, will deliver anything more than the basic USB-C spec of up to 5V@3A. It could even be limited to 900mA. This is completely separate from what it’s capable of accepting as a charging device. The DJI spec seems to imply that the best you could hope for is 15W.
You can test it with a device that supports higher power charging modes. When plugged, the device and drone will negotiate each other’s capabilities, and if the drone supports it, will switch to charging 30W. I doubt it will though.

Neither 1A or 2A are specs for Type-C port.

30W at 5V would be 6A, which is out of scope for Type-C interfaces, Power Delivery standards, connector ratings and cable ratings.
It surely will not output 30W at 5V, and if it charges at 30W, it means likely 15V at 2A or maybe 2.5A at 12V or 1.5A at 20V.
